# How to make on click an label combo box should appear

Tags: javascript

On click an label an combo box should appear...
please check http://guruji.com/en/local.html
on clicking near mycity the label changes into combobox (dropdown list)..how to do it.

Comment: Please clarify your question. It appears to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html) plugin for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

simple. you need to have two span element and play with js, css

```
  <span style='display:block' id="click me">
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementbyId('dropdownspan').style.display=hidden" select me</span><span style='display:hidden' id="dropdownspan">
 <select name="test"><option value="1">one</option></select>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking that link simply hides the original link and makes the "cities" dropdown visible. The dropdown is already on the page, you just can't see it.